# MongoDB Discord.js, uri is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js, robo3t

I was hooking up Mongo DB to my bot when an error showed up. Here's my coding in my main.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require('fs');
const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
client.prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();



fs.readdirSync('./events/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js')).forEach(events => {
    require(`./events/${events}`)(client, prefix);
});


['command_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
});

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODBSRV, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
}).then(() =>{
    console.log('Connected to the database!');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});


client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

I have no idea what's wrong because I'm really new to Mongo so I would love it if you gave some suggestions. I've just been following a tutorial (by Codelyon if you want to watch it) on how to hook it up. Here's my error:

```
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694:11)
    at C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:348:10     
    at C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1152:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:347:20)dex.js:347:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:24:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)                       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Note: It doesn't actually crash my bot. The rest of my code works perfectly.

Comment: is `process.env.MONGODBSRV` the token "as a string"?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. In my env, here's what it looks like `MONGODBSRV = <My connection>`

Comment: Can you try putting `require("dotenv").config()` at the top?

Comment: There already is. (If you mean in main.js)

Comment: Try adding `console.log(process.env.MONGODBSRV)` before the call to `mongoose.connect`

Comment: @Joe Thanks haha, I spelled the variable wrong in my `.env`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the problem is `process.env.MONGODBSRV`.

I think, you didn't define the value of `MONGODBSRV` in your `.env` file. Check it out !